# How to generate a new receive address for each transaction on the Nano Ledger S?

Tags: ledger-hardware-wallet, receiving

I am wondering if it is possible it have a new receive address each time I receive a crypto. Some exchanges do this for you automatically, but I noticed each time I hit 'display' it was the same address.

Is there a way to have a new receive address for each transactions?

Comment: It should show you a new address after you have a transaction on the previously displayed one automatically. Except for Ethereum, and ETC.

Comment: @RaghavSood Oh I see, I have not sent a transaction there yet so it's displaying the same one, thank you. if you post this as an answer I will accept!